# Update many documents in MongoDB (new Schema)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need some help with mongo client commands, i have to update every document in collection, this is my new ProductSchema:

```
const ProductSchema = Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: ''},
    price: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    image: { type: [String], default: [] },
    category: { type: String, default: '' },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

The old ProductSchema has as default `Product.image = null`. So i have a lot of products this way stored in DB. How can i update every document in my DB Collection if `Product.image == null` ? and then assign it an empty array (`Product.image = []`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `$set` operator. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/

Something like, `Product.updateMany({image : null}, {$set : { image : [] }})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to execute `update` query. As [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) explain method allows three fields:

- query: The selection criteria for the update.
- update: The modifications to apply.
- options: Like `multi`, `upsert` or whatever...

So, if you want to update only values where `image = null` you need to query only elements where: `image: null` and then do the update: `image: []`.

Using mongo you have to add `multi: true` in options to update all values and not only the first who match.

So the query is like this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "image": null
},
{
  "$set": {
    image: []
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4lKETrV7N15)

Also, if you are using mongoose you can call directly `updateMany()` and then you don't need `multi: true` option.